# Separate String into Array individually

Tags: java, arrays, string

How would you go about separating a string to an empty ***(specifically an empty one)*** array where each character is separated?

```
String word = "hello"
```

to

```
String[] wordSeparated = {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}
```

I believe there is a char function that I could use to find the letter, but I am unsure how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `split` method

```
String word = "hello"
String[] wordSeparated = word.split("");
```